# Outlook send-rule that filter on the 'From' field

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I use outlook (ms exchange) and have an individual as well as a group inbox (I'm logged in with the individual profile). I'm trying to setup a rule that will save a copy of a sent email in the group inbox if I sent the email 'From' the group email and another rule that will save a copy of a sent email in my individual inbox if I sent the email 'From' my individual email. However I cannot setup rules in the group inbox since the rules are client side and the group profile is normally not logged on and it is not possible to set a send-rule that filter on the 'From' field or Header content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use the [Rule Condition](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx) "through the specified account", then you need to create an [Outlook Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128768) or a [VBA Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736.aspx).

You cannot use [`Conditions.From`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._ruleconditions.from.aspx) filter for a send rule. You get...

> Invalid operation. This rule condition cannot be enabled because either the rule is read-only or invalid for the rule type, or the condition conflicts with another condition on the rule.

You could attach to the [`MailItem.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send) and modify the [`MailItem.SaveSentMessagesFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) after checking the [`MailItem.Sender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.sender)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I don't know how to create the VBA macro. Is this something you could show? If I for instance use individualMailboxA, groupMailboxB and groupMailboxC in Outlook (each mailbox with its own inbox), what would the complete VBA macro look like if I want email copies saved in the correct inbox depending on which of the three email addresses I used as 'From' when I sent the email?  I know this is asking for a lot - but I really don't even know where to start.  Many thanks

Comment: Glad it helped your direction. Your best bet is opening a new SO post with this specific question (*i.e. creating VBA macro to save email copy*) and refer to your original post. SO is a [Q & A site](http://stackoverflow.com/about). not a forum - new questions require a new post. Be sure to tag your new question with VBA and you are sure to get some script experts helping with your cause.

Comment: Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320072/creating-vba-macro-to-save-email-copy